# How do I change variable values in an javafx application after it has been instantiated?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a generic class that I can use for future projects. It just makes a simple javafx browser. The issue I'm having is that I want to be able to change some of the properties dynamically (on instantiation). I added some simple setters hoping it would to the job, but they do not work. Is there a way to change the variables after start() has been executed?

Class code:

```
package rob.rushton;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RushBrowser extends Application {

    public RushBrowser() {}

    private String url = "www.google.com";
    private final String fullUrl = "http://" + url;
    String title = "Simple Browser";
    private int height = 750;
    private int width = 750;

    public void openBrowser() {
        launch();
    }

    public void setURL(String u) {
        url = u;
    }

    public void setHeightWidth(int h, int w) {
        height = h;
        width = w;
    }

    public void setTitle(String t) {
        title = t;
    }

    @Override
     public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle(this.title);
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, width, height);
        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();
        engine.load(fullUrl);
        pane.setCenter(browser);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And I was trying to run it like this:

```
package rushtest;

import rob.rushton.RushBrowser;

public class RushTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RushBrowser rush = new RushBrowser();
        rush.setTitle("Test Title");
        rush.setURL("www.github.com");
        rush.setHeightWidth(1000, 1000);
        rush.openBrowser();
    }    
}
```

EDIT: (8/9/15) None of the listed suggestions below have worked :( The problem is that I do not know how to access the application thread that is started by launch()

Answer (score 1):

You should either make those properties true JavaFX properties, or update their setters delegate to the actual UI objects. Some rough code - only the relevant parts shown:

Case of true JavaFX properties:

```
public class RushBrowser extends Application {

    ...
    private StringProperty titleProperty = new SimpleStringProperty("Simple Browser");
    ...

    public void setTitle(String t) {
        titleProperty.set(t);
    }

    @Override
     public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.titleProperty().bind(this.titleProperty);
        ...
    }
}
```

Case of delegation - you also have to keep a reference of the `Stage`:

```
public class RushBrowser extends Application {

    ...
    private Stage primaryStage;
    // no need to keep the title member variable
    ...

    public void setTitle(String t) {
        primaryStage.setTitle(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        this.primaryStage = stage;
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

As per the comment from James_D, there is another problem: the main method has no reference to the instance created by `Application.launch()`. So:

1. If you want to customize the parameters of your application before it starts, you can override `Application.init()`:

   ```
   public class SpecialRushBrowser extends RushBrowser {
       public void init() {
           this.setTitle("Test Title");
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   Or from the test code:

   ```
   public class RushTest {
       static class TestRushBrowser extends RushBrowser {
           public void init() {
               super.init(); // just in case
               this.setTitle("Test Title");
               ...
           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           TestRushBrowser.launch();
       }
   }
   ```

   If you do not need to modify these parameters later, you can leave your code as is (i.e. no JavaFX properties are required). Otherwise, apply the changes mentioned above.
2. If you want to change the parameters after the application has started, you need to provide a reference to the actual instance of `RushBrowser` created by `Application.launch()` to the code that will execute the changes. A simple but **dirty** way is with a global variable:

   ```
   public class RushBrowser extends Application {
       public static RushBrowser INSTANCE;

       public void init() {
           INSTANCE = this;
       }

       ...
   }
   ```

   And then from any code that runs after `launch()`:

   ```
   RushBrowser.INSTANCE.setTitle(...);
   ...
   ```

   As global state is generally dangerous, you might want to try with a dependency injection framework, if the application gets more complex. Even with DI though it can get tricky because the main class is still created from JavaFX, outside the DI framework - but that's another story.

   Again you need to apply the changes above the EDIT.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, does it? (The problem being that the instance created by the `launch()` method is not the same instance on which the OP was setting values.) How are you going to run it?

Comment: @James_D Yes you are right; this solves half of the problem, i.e. having a *correct* reference of `RushBrowser`, actually set its properties. Updating answer...

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos is "stage.titleProperty.bind(this.titleProperty);"  the correct syntax?

Comment: @RobRushton You are right, it is actually a method so it should be `stage.titleProperty()...` -> correcting in answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code you posted doesn't work is that the (`static`) `launch(...)` method creates a new instance of the `Application` subclass for you, and then calls *its* `start(...)` method. So the instance for which you call all the `setXXX(...)` methods is not the instance whose `start(...)` method is invoked.

You're defining the reusable part in the wrong place: an `Application` subclass is inherently not reusable. You should regard the `start()` method in your `Application` subclass as the equivalent of the `main()` method in a regular JavaFX application.

So:

```
public class RushBrowser {

    private final BorderPane view ;

    private String url = "www.google.com";
    private final String fullUrl = "http://" + url;
    private String title = "Simple Browser";
    private int height = 750;
    private int width = 750;

    private WebEngine engine ;

    public RushBrowser() {
        WebView browser = new WebView();
        view = new BorderPane(browser);
        engine = browser.getEngine();
    }

    public Node getView() {
        return view ;
    }

    public void show(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(view, width, height);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void show() {
        show(new Stage());
    }

    public void setURL(String u) {
        url = u;
    }

    public void setHeightWidth(int h, int w) {
        height = h;
        width = w;
        view.setPrefSize(w, h);
    }

    public void setTitle(String t) {
        title = t;
        Scene scene = view.getScene();
        if (scene != null) {
            Window window = scene.getWindow();
            if (window instanceof Stage) {
                ((Stage)window).setTitle(title);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

and then you test it with an `Application` subclass:

```
public class RushBrowserTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        RushBrowser rush = new RushBrowser();
        rush.setTitle("Test Title");
        rush.setURL("www.github.com");
        rush.setHeightWidth(1000, 1000);
        rush.show(primaryStage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

and of course you can use it elsewhere. As an arbitrary example:

```
TabPane tabPane = ... ;

RushBrowser rush = new RushBrowser();
rush.setURL("www.github.com");
Tab tab = new Tab();
tab.setContent(rush.getView());
```